# php navigate to previous page after login workaround

Tags: php, javascript, authentication

So for some reason, I tried http_referer and it isn't working for me...or maybe it is but this is the reason why I'm trying a workaround.  I'm testing a login script in my browser and I want the user to go back to the previous page which they were visiting.

The issue I ran into is when I put in my login credentials, Firefox and Chrome pop out a "Save Password" option and I THINK it acts like a page.  So when http_referer is called or when

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">javascript:history.go(-1);</script>';
```

The page is still on the login page!  Well what if the user clicks once "Don't Save" and that option is saved...then using history.go(-2) wouldn't work.  Here's the workaround I tried but I can't get it to work.

Initially if the login info is correct, I call the first history.go(-1).  Then I'm using this function to get the current page and if it matches login.php, I want to go back one more page!  But it's not working.  Please advise me

```
if($login_check > 0){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">javascript:history.go(-1);</script>';
    function curPageName() {
        return substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
    }
    $curpage = curPageName();
    if ($curpage = "login.php"){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">javascript:history.go(-1);</script>';
    }
}
```

I've also read to use sessions but my session array saves data for the shopping cart so I'm not sure how I would use sessions for navigation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not store the URL of the page that redirects to the login page in a session and then redirect to it on a successful login? That way even if the user has a few failed login attempts they'll still get to the right page.

Another benefit for this method over javascript is that the redirect is sent in the header on page request, no need to send the user js.

Save the URL as a session variable when the user is not logged in.

```
// not logged in
$_SESSION['redirect_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
//now redirect to login page, something like
header("Location: http://www.site.com/login");
```

*Nb. The URL above is crudely constructed, if you are using SSL or a different port (not 80) you'll need to change it accordingly.*

Retrieve it on successful login

```
//login successful 
header("Location: ".$_SESSION['redirect_url']);
exit;
```

Comment: please help me out because I'm still trying to figure things out.  If I'm storing values in a session throughout my site, will this session override that session?  Or are they all separate based on their variables?  What I'm planning on doing is if someone is adding stuff to their shopping cart, I'm storing it in an array in a session.  Then when user logs in, I'm going to merge them (somehow). Will your way mess up the initial session?

Comment: You can save lots of session variables. Setting $_SESSION['redirect_url'] will only overwrite $_SESSION['redirect_url'], it won't affect any other session data. If you want to see what session data is being store and under what variable name you can do this: <?php print_r($_SESSION); ?>

Comment: ok, thanks Nick.  I'll look into it and try to understand more.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: It would be helpful to understand associative arrays, that's what the PHP session is. A nice overview of session can be found here: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php

Comment: Hey Nick, I have a quick question about your function.  In the first part you're saying to save the current URL in a session but why are you redirecting to the login page?  What is that for?  I just want to keep updating the current URL in that session and the user can go to login whenever they want, not to redirect them.  Can you modify your code or do I just leave out the redirecting header?

Comment: That's very straight forward, just don't include the redirect part. So, on every page that isn't the login page save the url to a session with: $_SESSION['redirect_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

Comment: That's what I figured.  Thanks for your help again.